# Which are the steps the union functon goes through?

Tags: qgis, union, function

While skimming the union function I could see it works with intersecting bounding boxes, layer features and attributes. But how, exactly does this function work; which are the lines that check for intersection, compose new features, adds the attributes to those features, etc?

Comment: I doubt it is done in qgis, but in the gdal driver it uses.

Comment: [ArcGIS](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//000800000010000000) gives quite a nice description on how Union works which would be somewhat similar to what happens in QGIS. Since you used the [`code`](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code) tag, you could look into the [Union script for QGIS](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/Union.py) as it is opensource.

Comment: This question is quite broad and somewhat abstract. The source is available for review.  You'll see that each feature is compared with *every* feature (using a spatial index where available). If there is a particular aspect of the process that confuses you, please **edit** this question to focus on that.

Comment: Thanks, I'll continue reviewing the function, and add more process oriented questions as they arise.